# Code coverage for GUI based functional tests

Tags: selenium, code-coverage, functional-testing, emma, jacoco

I am trying to get bytecode coverage analysis using a code coverage tool (like Emma or Jacoco) after testing with a GUI based functional testing tool (like HP QuickTest Pro or Selenium).

Anyone who has done this could please give me an idea to start this project?

Comment: Bytecode coverage? Why would you want that? You mean, "source code" coverage?

Comment: I am supposed to present a solution that works on compiled java *.class files without access to source code for confidentiality reasons I think.

Comment: "You think"?  This is the classic problem with requirements; they aren't crystal clear when the project starts.   If you insist on doing it with just class files, you may not get good coverage data.  If you're lucky, the class files contain line number data, and you can at best get information about whether a "line" is roughly covered.   But you can' know what *in* the line is covered; what if the line contains several conditionals?  Nor can you get much beyond a "% covered" based on the lines you see.   Finally, you can't say anything about uncovered lines, except they aren't covered.

Comment: ... this kills a lot of the value of a test coverage tool.  Are you sure of this requirement?

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ira, I should check out with the client to make sure of his needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing this now.  My approach is to use JaCoCo ant tasks to instrument the binary byte-code files, and use a specific CLASSPATH to execute the instrumented binaries from an ant build.xml from Jenkins.

The reason for doing the code coverage from byte-code is that there is an existing set-up that runs test scripts for a large application using HP QuickTest Pro .  I would imagine that the test coverage is in the single digits, but we need an empirical baseline to demonstrate the possible improvements in code coverage from doing unit tests during a build.